# Presenting a view controller modally within a navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uistoryboardsegue

here's my situation:

I have two view controllers embedded in a Navigation controller. I'll call them Sender and Destination

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to "replace" the Sender with the Destination in the navigation stack such that pressing a button on the Sender segues to the Destination but pressing the "< Back" button in the navigation bar for both the Sender and the Destination will lead to the same view controller.

Here's the problem: I want the transition between these two view controllers to be a Horizontal Flip, so I created a segue connecting the Sender and the Destination with kind "Present Modally", transition "Flip Horizontal", .
In Sender I select the "Defines Context" option.

Now, for the connecting segue:

-When I select "Over Current Context" for presentation it does exactly what I want! ...Except the animation looks a little wonky. Basically the Sender stays flat and static while the Destination flips above it, as opposed to them flipping "together". This makes sense because the segue is presenting *over* the Sender, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

-When I select "Current Context" for presentation the animation looks great! ...Except if I press the "< Back" button in the navigation bar, it just leads to a plain black view with a navigation bar and if I press the "< Back" button again on this view I get the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
```

Anybody have any idea how I can achieve what I'm trying to do? Is this even the right approach?
I've seen some suggestions to try and flip the view controller's view to a new view instead of flipping the entire view controller to a different view controller. But is it possible to have two "full-sized" views for one view controller in the storyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are various approaches that could work, but my first thought would be to create a container view for the Sender and Destination views.

So you have ...

- NavigationController with Root View Controller ("RVC")
- Container View Controller ("CVC")
- Sender VC
- Destination VC

Instead of "RVC" segueing to "Sender" you segue to "CVC" ... "CVC" initially loads "Sender" into its "container view" ... At this point, tapping <Back takes you, naturally, back to "RVC"

When you tap a button (or whatever you use to initiate the next transition) to go to "Destination" you can use a transition with "replace Sender with Destination" *inside the container view* ... and at that point, since "CVC" is still the top-of-the-stack view controller, tapping <Back will again take you back to "RVC"

Hope that makes sense :)

Demo example available here: https://github.com/DonMag/ContainerViewExample

Comment: Hmm so how would the replacing action work? Would I still be using a similar Horizontal Flip segue? If so, wouldn't I run into the same problem as before only in this case it would be in CVC instead of the Sender VC?

Comment: No, you wouldn't be using a segue... take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622574-transition

Comment: If you're still working on this, I put up a demo app at: https://github.com/DonMag/ContainerViewExample

Comment: Thanks so much!! It's close to what I was looking for and helped me get it!